# minimal diameter of sphere with sectional curvature bounded above

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assuming that $g$ is a metric on the n-dimensional sphere $S^n(n\geq 3)$ satisfying sectional curvature bounded: $|K(g)|\leq 1$, is the diameter of $g$ at least $\pi$? How about if we only assume that $K(g)\leq 1$?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer now, but there is a paper by Buser and Gromoll (with title something about almost non-negative metrics on $S^3$) which shows that under the assumption $K(g)\leq 1$, the diameter may be as small as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

If $0<h\leq K \leq H$ everywhere, then it is a result of Mei-Chin Ku (PAMS, 1976) that

$$D\geq \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{H}}.$$

Comment: In my understanding, his proof is wrong because he used Klingenberg's estimate of injectivity radius without the assumption of even dimension or pinching of positive curvature.

Comment: @FengWang Interesting! Is this well-known (that this is wrong), or did you just notice it?

Comment: I don't hear of the paper before. I just read and thought it's wrong.